# Selenium - How to execute a command while WebDriverWait wait.until is running

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to execute a command while waiting for an element to appear? In particular I'm waiting for an element to appear but it's not going to appear unless I refresh the page. Here's my code

```
wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("xpath_here")));
state = element.getText();
```

The element I'm waiting for is never going to appear unless I hit the app's refresh button. How can I refresh during the 30 second timeout that I set?

Comment: Why won't you just refresh and then wait for the element? Why do you have to refresh **during** the wait?

Comment: Well I do a refresh before the wait but the element may not still not be there in which case it will fail because no matter how long I wait unless I refresh again the element won't appear. I guess I could put the wait inside a loop so I can refresh and wait several times.

Comment: So you have to refresh multiple times? Do you have the limit for refreshes? (number or time)

Comment: I would have to refresh until the element pops up, every 5 seconds for instance and if at the 30 second timeout the element is still not there then I give up and exit.

Comment: I've updated my answer: checks for 5 seconds then refreshes... all this is happening for 30 seconds

Comment: @AlexOkrushko thanks I'll give it a shot and get back to you. really appreciate it

Comment: Check here 
>http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418004/webdriverwait-search-for-an-item/23433717#23433717

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
    System.out.println("before wait");
    WebElement el = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
      .until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>(){
        //try the following cycle for 30 seconds
        @Override
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
            //refresh the page
            driver.navigate().refresh();

            System.out.println("Refreshed");
            //look for element for 5 seconds
            WebElement sameElement = null;
            try{
                sameElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 5))
                      .until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>(){
                    @Override
                    public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
                        System.out.println("Looking for the element");
                        return driver.findElement(By.id("theElementYouAreLookingFor"));
                    }});    
            } catch (TimeoutException e){
                // if NULL is returns the cycle starts again
                return sameElement;
            } 
            return sameElement;
    }});        
    System.out.println("Done");
```

It will try to get the element for 30 seconds, refreshing the page every 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I would add more lines to that code:   basically, if state.isEmpty()  then use a Webdriver "Action" class to move the mouse to the refresh button (you app would need a refresh button inside of it for this to work) then run the wait one more time to verify it appears.